# Create new ArrayList based on another Collection

Tags: java

I cant understand the meaning of `new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i))`, the output of `subsets.get(i)` is list,why?

```
// the findSubsets method.i think the main method is easy, so i dont put it down.
/** Given a set with distinct elements, find all of its distinct subsets.
    Examples1:
    Input: [1, 3]
    Outout: [], [1], [3], [1,3]

    Examples2:
    Input: [1, 5, 3]
    Output: [], [1], [5], [3], [1,5], [1,3], [5,3], [1,5,3]
*/
public static List<List<Integer>> findSubsets(int[] nums) {

        //empty subset
        List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
        subsets.add(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int currentNumber : nums) {
            int n = subsets.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println(subsets.get(i));
                
                // below line
                List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i));
                set.add(currentNumber);
                subsets.add(set);
            }
        }
        return subsets;
```

Comment: what part of it don't you understand? subset is of type: List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>(); so each of it's elements a List<Integer>

Comment: may be it means we can add new list but dont need to change the previous list?

Comment: have you checked the api of ArrayList? checked what that constructor does?

Comment: i uploaded the picture which shows the constructor(ArrayList).In official java doc , it means the int type but here is the list type,its different.@Stultuske

Comment: @muji - Read Stultuske's comment again.  Your response indicates that either you didn't understand it, or you ignored it.  He said read the javadoc **for the constructor**.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> set = new ArrayList<>(subsets.get(i));
```

You are creating a List instance(`set`) from another collection(`subsets.get(i)`).

> `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
> in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-

Comment: thanks , but why not use the code like this `List<Integer>  set = subsets.get(i);`

Comment: You need to dry run the code. This is a logical error you have in your code. I cannot give you the answer as you didn't explain what you want to achieve from this method. Take a pen and a paper. Go through the code and you will understand.

Comment: Erm ... because you are **copying** the list.  There could be (good) reasons for doing that, but we can't infer them from the information you have provided.